# Position View within Container programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

OK, so this is my situation :

- I've got a View (an `NSBox` actually) with variable bounds (I'm changing them programmatically)
- Within the `NSBox` we've got another view (an `NSTextField`).

What I want to do is to be able to position the subview, relatively to the superview, programmatically.

**E.g. :**

- Center
- Top Left
- Top Right
- Bottom Left
- Bottom Right

Is there any Cocoa-friendly way this could be achieved?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to calculate the frame of the subview relative to the `NSBox` and then use `subview.frame = rect;`.  There is no shortcut way around this I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true - on later versions of OS X you could use auto-layout instead, rather than manipulating the frame directly.

Comment: @trojanfoe That's a great question : can it be used programmatically? if this is true, that'd be definitely amazing. :-)

Comment: Yep, you can use the visual format language, and add / remove them programatically. Although if you haven't used auto-layout before it can take a while to wrap your head around it. Definitely worth watching the WWDC video to get to grips with VFL, it's not exactly intuitive: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH2-SW2

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at `NSLayoutConstraint` [(apple docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html) -- and [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265308/adding-objects-to-an-nsview/12266902#12266902) for an example of using this class. It would be pretty easy to make a convenience method for setting the constraints to "top-right" or "center" or whatever.